# How to correctly model a receiving antenna?

Tags: amplifier, rf, antenna, gsm

I want to amplify the signal received by an antenna for GSM signals. I am currently modeling the antenna as a 900 MHz sinewave generator and a 50 Ω resistance in series with it. However, I doubt this model's accuracy.

So knowing the power received using the Friis equation, and knowing the VSWR of the receiving antenna, how can I correctly model it for simulation (voltage, lumped model)?

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/321726175_Impedance_Analysis_of_Mobile_Phone_Antenna_in_the_Presence_of_User%27s_Hand

Comment: Well, if the antenna is properly matched, then that model is accurate, else, it isn't. We don't know your antenna and matching circuitry, and to which degree of accuracy you can model

Comment: The circuit is just a simulation, I'm assuming an antenna with 50Ohm impedance matched and a VSWR of 2, gain of 4DB